# Lit Localize and Dynamic expressions

Tags: localization, language-translation, lit

I have a screen using Lit, and we use @lit/localize for our language translation.

With our design, on this screen, the server returns a key/value pair of strings to display on the screen. The key of these pairs is somewhat dynamic, in that they can be dynamically added as a possible value, without needing to re-compile the server side that is providing these expressions.

While I realize this isn't the best case, and that also on the lit or UI side of things I have to provide the translation.  In other languages where the localization is just a key/value pair to a string file, I add them. With lit/localize there is the added process of generating the translation files, and it appears to assign them a unique id.

My solution is to either do some sort of fake method where I provide msg('Some Dynamic String').  The code is never called, but it will allow me to generate the proper token in the localized files.

The other option I can think of is to have a big case statement where I am building this list and translating it that way.

Is there a better way that I am not thinking of? Has anyone solved a problem similar to this in the past, with or without lit/localize?

Comment: I can't think of a definitive answer. If you want to rely on lit localize extract, you would need to do what you propose of adding `msg` calls into your code. It is possible to specify the id https://lit.dev/docs/localization/overview/#overriding-ids so you could add those to your translations manually with the id too. I suppose the backend providing the key would have to provide an id too. Or use the key as id if it's unique enough. This might be problematic for maintenance though as subsequent extract calls might overwrite the manually added ones.